# Regex Replacing Multiple Characters

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

What I have is a program that takes user's input from a textbox and adds a period to the end of it. The problem I'm trying to solve is if the user puts a period at the end of what they have typed then I want to be able to remove that period. I tried to use the string replace method but that only lets you do it for a single character. The next thing I thought about was regular expressions.

I tried this:

```
finalString = Regex.Replace(finalString, "..", ".");
```

but all it did was replace every character with a period. Is there a regular expression that would let me replace 2 periods that are next to each other?

Comment: A dot / period (`.`) is a special character in regex (meaning any character) so you need to escape `\` it if you want to check on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` has a special meaning so you need to escape it with `\`

```
finalString = Regex.Replace(finalString, "\\.\\.$", ".");
```

or simply use verbatim symbol

```
finalString = Regex.Replace(finalString, @"\.\.$", ".");
```

adding `$` at the end of the regex asserts if the position of the period is on the last part of the string.

Comment: When I try to escape it with a \ it gives me an error saying Unrecognized escape sequence

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use any of these characters as a literal in a regex, you need to escape them with a backslash.

the opening square bracket `[`, the backslash `\`, the caret `^`, the dollar sign `$`, the period or dot `.`, the vertical bar or pipe symbol `|`, the question mark `?`, the asterisk or star `*`, the plus sign `+`, the opening round bracket `(` and the closing round bracket `)`.

[**Good Read**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1):

`.` in regular expression means match any character..In your case `..` means match any two characters and replace it with `.`

You should escape it like this `\.`

It should be

`finalString = Regex.Replace(finalString, @"\.\.", ".");`

Comment: @RandomlyKnighted its is just a `verbatim string`..it has nothing to do with `regex`...it allows us to have `\n` or other escape characters to have **no special meaning**..so if you use `"\n"` it will print `newline`..if you use `@"\n"` it will print `\n` not `newline`..

Comment: @RandomlyKnighted if you dont want `@""` use `\\` instead of just `\`